# Views Bulk Operations & Draggable Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am in a situation where I need my end user to be able to organise a list of nodes using drag and drop. To do this I would normally be able to use *Draggable Views*. I also need the user to be able to bulk update the nodes returned. Normally I would use *Views Bulk Operation*. Is there anyway I can use both modules together? Would I need to code something myself or can you think of another way I can do what I want.

- Sortable Content by dragging
- In-line updating of content a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are both style plugins, I doubt you'll be able to get them to both work on the same page. What about creating separate page displays for the same view, each with its own style plugin and each with its own tab. One tab could be "Update" and the other "Organize".

Comment: That seems to be the best way I can think of without writing a new style that contains both features.

Comment: Both of those modules can work fine together.. I have successfully accomplished this in a recent project. [in D7, btw].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and opened an issue at the Modle site http://drupal.org/node/1222742
. My Solution was exactly what has been suggested above. Creating 2 different displays for the view, one to update using VBO and the other to organize. If you know of or have found a better solution please post and share.